# Filtering result based on a status in Laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel

I have an order list in my admin panel, I want to use tabs to separate the orders based on the status

I defined the statuses in **my Model**:

```
public static $statuses = [
    'done' =>  'Successful Orders',
    'canceled' => 'Canceled Orders',
    'pending'=> 'Pending Orders'
    ];
```

Here are **my tabs (`bootstrap`)**:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#pending">Pending Orders</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#done">Successful Orders</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#canceled">Canceled Orders</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="pending" class="tab-pane fade in active">
       //ORDERS WITH PENDING STATUS
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="done" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      //ORDERS WITH DONE STATUS
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="canceled" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      //ORDERS WITH CANCELED STATUS
    </div>
  </div>
```

Now I want to display this data on each tab based on **status**:

```
   @foreach($orders as $order)
        {{ $order->id }}
        {{ $order::$statuses[$order->status] }}
   @endforeach
```

Comment: Can you not groupBy using Laravel collections? Something like: ```collect($orders)->groupBy(function($order) { return Order::statuses[$order->status]; });``` - The orders might already be a collection so you probably wont need to use collect(). See more here: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-groupby

Answer (score 0):

**CONTROLLER**

```
function index() {
  if(request()->has('status')) {
    $orders = Order::where('status', request('status'))->paginate(5)->append('status', request('status'));
  }

  return view('orders.index', compact('orders'));
}
```

**View**

```
<a href="/orders?status=pending">Pending</a>
<a href="/orders?status=done">Pending</a>
<a href="/orders?status=canceled">Pending</a>

foreach($orders as $order) {
  $order->id;
}
```

Comment: Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::append does not exist.

Comment: sorry it should be `appends()` with s